# « Super super beau » : la redondance change quelque chose à l'emploi adverbial et à l'orthographe ?

Tags: adjectifs, orthographe, adverbes, préfixes, trait-d-union

Je lis que :

> [...] dans un registre familier, *super* est parfois considéré comme
> un adverbe lorsqu’il précède un adjectif. Il a alors le sens de «
> remarquablement, extrêmement ». Dans ces emplois, *super* est
> évidemment toujours invariable et il demeure détaché de l’adjectif qui
> le suit.
>
> [Banque de de dépannage linguistique (OQLF), [*super-*]](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1397)

> Il va être vraiment super beau, comme tous les châteaux du Moyen
> Âge,
>  **Super super** beau. [*La guerre des tuques*]

C'est le « haut haut » degré. Mais comment l'analyse-t-on quand il est employé deux fois comme dans l'exemple : le premier *super* est-il aussi adverbe dans un tel cas ; peut/devrait-on avoir le trait d'union (*super-super beau*) ou l'agglutination ?

Comment: Pourquoi la question a pris -1 ? Que pourrait-on améliorer ? Pourquoi ce vote gratuit ?

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi c'est un cas particulier de superlatif absolu.

Si nous avions :

> Il est super beau.

ce serait un superlatif absolu normal, avec l'adjectif *beau* qui est modifié par l'adverbe *super*.

Dans :

> Il est (2)super (1)super beau.

l'adverbe (1)*super* modifie *beau*, et l'adverbe (2)*super* modifie (1)*super*.

On pourrait aussi dire qu'il y a redondance de l'adverbe *super* pour modifier *beau*. Ça ne changerait rien à l'affaire. De toutes façons pas de trait d'union car il n'y a pas pour moi formation d'un mot composé.

Answer (score 0):

En complément de l'analyse de None, les linguistes appellent ce procédé où un adverbe d'intensité est répété, une ***réduplication intensive adverbiale***  comme par exemple dans :

> C'est pas **très très** malin.

Références:

[Des moyens d'expression de l'intensité dans le langage des jeunes Québécois, Chantale Bilaudeau](https://constellation.uqac.ca/910/1/12335073.pdf), §6.13.1